# Non-deprecated methods to retrieve images from a plist in cocos2d-x

Tags: plist, deprecated, cocos2d-x

i have to load images on the screen from a plist and I am using the following code

```
CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("level1.plist");

CCSpriteBatchNode *bgBatch = CCSpriteBatchNode::batchNodeWithFile("level1.png");
this->addChild(bgBatch);

CCSprite *bg = CCSprite::spriteWithSpriteFrameName("jug.png");
    bg->setPosition(ccp(30,115));
    bgBatch->addChild(bg);
```

but the functions "batchNodeWithFile" and "spriteWithSpriteFrameName" are deprecated. what functions should I use instead of these?

thanks for helping but i'v tried this but when I run it

---

thanks for helping but i'v tried this and when I run it

```
    CCSprite* CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName(const char *pszSpriteFrameName)
        {
            CCSpriteFrame *pFrame = CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()-   >spriteFrameByName(pszSpriteFrameName);
#if COCOS2D_DEBUG > 0
            char msg[256] = {0};
            sprintf(msg, "Invalid spriteFrameName: %s", pszSpriteFrameName);
            CCAssert(pFrame != NULL, msg); /* it stops right here and gives error "Assertion failed: (pFrame != __null), function createWithSpriteFrameName, file /Users/gameview/Desktop/mahwish/mahwish/libs/cocos2dx/sprite_nodes/CCSprite.cpp, line 158."

        #endif
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Static constructors in Cocos2d-x have been renamed so that they all start with `create`, so

- `CCSpriteBatchNode::batchNodeWithFile` turned to just **`CCSpriteBatchNode::create`**
- `CCSprite::spriteWithSpriteFrameName` turned to **`CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName`**